# Mongoose schematype.castForQuery error. User authentication failed

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport-local, passport-facebook

I have a problem while using passport strategy using local-passport using node js and mongoose. Sometimes(not always) it shows the following error to which I could not figure out and I could not login to the system. I have used angular JS for client side.

```
TypeError: schematype.castForQuery is not a function
at cast (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:229:32)
at Query.cast (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2753:12)
at Query.findOne (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1353:10)
at Function.findOne (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1343:13)
at Strategy._verify (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/app_api/config/passport.js:17:8)
at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:90:12)
at attempt (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
at authenticate (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
at module.exports.login (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/app_api/controllers/authentication.js:302:4)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/Harry/Desktop/socketio/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

Here is my code for which the error's pointing:
I tried to login, but it says the above errors sometimes(not always).I could not find the errors.

```
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 400, {
        "message": "All fields Required."
    });
    return;
}

passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    var token;
    if (err) {

        sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
        return;
    }
    // console.log('user detail : '+user);
    if (user && user.verified === true) {
        token = user.generateJwt();
        sendJSONresponse(res, 200, {
            "token": token
        });

    } else {
        sendJSONresponse(res, 401, info);

    }

})(req, res); // make sure that req, res are available to the passport

};
```

Here is code for passport strategy :

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
},
function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({
        email: username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("passport_error : "+err);
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                "message": "Incorrect Username."
            });
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, {
                "message": "Incorrect Password." + password
            });
        }
        console.log(user);
        return done(null, user);

    });
}
));
```

Comment: Please add the following line of logging. If the output is not `{}` then that is your problem. `console.log("Object.prototype:", Object.prototype);`

Comment: @joeytwiddle Yeah I did it. At first I got {}. And I could login successfully. But when I start chat with somebody and logout from the system, then I could not log in. My given email reaches upto inside of function in my passport ( function(username, password, done) { ) . Here the username is printed whatever email I give, but it doesnot go beyound this and check from database. And this time I got ( Object.prototype:  { getKey: [Function] } ) instead of {} . Can you figure out, what might be the case? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. Now it works. I had used the following code using Object.prototype....

```
    Object.prototype.getKey = function(value) {
        for (var key in this) {
            if (this[key] == value) {
                return key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
    var key = usernames.getKey(toUser);
```

It successfully returned the key of certain value (toUser in my case). However, everytime I logout of the system, it was not working and was not logging back in. 
Now I removed the entire method and replace with following code...

```
    function findKey(user) {
        for (var key in usernames) {
            if (usernames[key] == user) return key;
        }
        return false;
    }
    var key= findKey(toUser);
```

Which is simpler way to return key of cetrain value in JSON object. And Now, there is not a problem in my mongodb findOne method. Still couldnot figured out the reason behind the errors by using Object.prototype method to return key. However the strange error is gone with small changes.

SO, if you guys were stuck in same error type (Schematype.castForQuery is not a function ), it might be helpful

Thank you for your response though.